# Move duplicate values to another column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with pairs of entries based on the column id_location.

```
"id_image",  "score",  "stddev", "id_image2", "score2", "stddev2", "id_location"
3484,        0.90422,  0.06476,  NULL,        NULL,     NULL,      13
18,          0.71598,  0.06101,  NULL,        NULL,     NULL,      13
```

If I wanted to merge duplicates for id_location and move them to a different column so each row is unique, how would I do that?

I looked at transpose and pivot but those seem slightly different.

This would be the resulting table:

```
"id_image",  "score",  "stddev", "id_image2", "score2", "stddev2", "id_location"
3484,        0.90422,  0.06476,  18,          0.71598,   0.06101,  13
```

Comment: I have a CSV in Python or a MySQL database to play with.  This only needs to be done once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do it, with the higher `id_image` appearing in the first slot:

```
INSERT INTO new_table
SELECT t1.id_image, t1.score, t1.stddev, t2.id_image,
  t2.score, t2.stddev, t1.id_location
FROM old_table t1
JOIN old_table t2
ON t2.id_location = t1.id_location
  AND t2.id_image < t1.id_image
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using subqueries :

```
UPDATE your_table
 SET
  score2 = (SELECT score FROM your_table WHERE id_image = 3484),
  stddev2 = (SELECT stddev FROM your_table WHERE id_image = 3484),
 WHERE id_image = 18;
```