# Move duplicated values into unique columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I found a similar problem here: [Move duplicate values to another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219048/move-duplicate-values-to-another-column), but I'm not sure that is going to work for me.

Here's how the data is set up:

```
Account_ID  Phone Number  Phone Number ID
1           1             1
1           2             2
1           3             3
1           4             4
1           5             5
1           6             6
2           1             1
2           2             2
2           3             3
2           4             4
2           5             5
2           6             6
```

Each Account ID has one entry for each of the 6 phone numbers. I want it to look like this:

```
Account_ID  Phone Number 1  Phone Number 2  Phone Number 3  etc.
1           1               2               3
2           2               2               2
```

I've tried using a `CASE` statement like this:

```
SELECT
Account_ID,
CASE Phone Number ID
WHEN 1 THEN Phone Number END AS "Phone Number 1"
CASE Phone Number ID
WHEN 2 THEN Phone Number END AS "Phone Number 1"
etc.…
GROUP BY 
Case CASE Phone Number ID
WHEN 1 THEN Phone Number END
etc.…
```

But it still doesn't properly consolidate the data to a single row for each Account_ID. It put the Phone Number that corresponds with the Phone Number ID in the correct column, but each Account_ID is still it's own row.

Any thoughts? The link I supplied above is way too nested, slow, and clunky for this many fields. I wrote a version of it anyway to test it out, but it's been running for going on 15 minutes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **PIVOT** to get the output you need.

```
select * from 
(table1 
   pivot (max("Phone Number") for "Phone Number ID"
  in ('1' as "Phone Number 1",
      '2' as "Phone Number 2",
      '3' as "Phone Number 3",
      '4' as "Phone Number 4",
      '5' as "Phone Number 5",
      '6' as "Phone Number 6"))
 )
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ebe14/17)**

Comment: to match the column names you can do  `in ('1' as 'Phone Number 1','2' as 'Phone Number 2'...`

Comment: The pivot works perfectly! Thank you so much. I had no idea there was a pivot option. Looks like it is new to Oracle after doing some research.

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  You need a `case` and a `max` and a `group by`:

```
select Account_ID,
       max(CASE Phone Number ID = 1 then Phone Number end) as "Phone Number 1",
       max(CASE Phone Number ID = 2 then Phone Number end) as "Phone Number 2",
       max(CASE Phone Number ID = 3 then Phone Number end) as "Phone Number 3",
       . . .
from . . .
group by Account_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a bunch of joins

```
WITH accounts 
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT account_id 
         FROM   phones) 
SELECT a.account_id, 
       one.phone_number   phone_number_1, 
       two.phone_number   phone_number_2, 
       three.phone_number phone_number_3, 
       four.phone_number  phone_number_4, 
       five.phone_number  phone_number_5, 
       six.phone_number   phone_number_6 
FROM   accounts a 
       LEFT JOIN phones one 
              ON a.account_id = one.account_id 
                 AND one.phone_number_id = 1 
       LEFT JOIN phones two 
              ON two.account_id = two.account_id 
                 AND two.phone_number_id = 2 
       LEFT JOIN phones three 
              ON a.account_id = three.account_id 
                 AND three.phone_number_id = 3 
       LEFT JOIN phones four 
              ON a.account_id = four.account_id 
                 AND four.phone_number_id = 4 
       LEFT JOIN phones five 
              ON a.account_id = five.account_id 
                 AND five.phone_number_id = 5 
       LEFT JOIN phones six 
              ON a.account_id = six.account_id 
                 AND six.phone_number_id = 6
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6bebf/5)