# SQL move a duplicate value to a new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I found a similar problem here: [Move duplicated values into unique columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712836/move-duplicated-values-into-unique-columns), but I'm not sure that is going to work for me.

The data provided looks like this:

```
email_address    barcode           value    
1@aol.com        9X3BZBK9CPWVDT16  25
123@verizon.net  9X3L6RD1Y83J8Z6Q  50
123@verizon.net  9X3PWCQRNX2CNJBC  50
2@naver.com      9X3N438B6TZYRD1N  50
3@msn.com        9X3PVFJ2N3C2DNW6  25
456@yahoo.com    9X3BCJ3YXFQ1RFGU  50
456@yahoo.com    9X3L1DVG89CGDBB0  25
```

But I would like to have it look like this:

```
EMAIL_ADDRESS    BURNED_BARCODE1    value1    BURNED_BARCODE2    value2        
1@aol.com        9X3BZBK9CPWVDT16   25
123@verizon.net  9X3L6RD1Y83J8Z6Q   50        9X3PWCQRNX2CNJBC   50
2@naver.com      9X3N438B6TZYRD1N   50
3@msn.com        9X3PVFJ2N3C2DNW6   25
456@yahoo.com    9X3BCJ3YXFQ1RFGU   50        9X3L1DVG89CGDBB0   25
```

I am trying to consolidate the duplicate coupon codes and values into a BARCODE_2 and value2. I have thought about pivot tables but i cannot seem to get the logic to work.

Any thoughts? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am using sql server

Comment: Pivot could be one way to go. What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function for this and a self-join:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY email_address ORDER BY barcode) AS RN
              FROM Table1)
SELECT a.email_address, a.barcode, a.value, b.barcode AS barcode2, b.value AS value2
FROM cte a
LEFT JOIN cte b
 ON a.email_address = b.email_address
  AND a.RN = b.RN -1
WHERE a.RN = 1
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3c5f0/4/0)

Update: You could add a 3rd:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY email_address ORDER BY barcode) AS RN
              FROM Table1)
SELECT a.email_address, a.barcode, a.value
     , b.barcode AS barcode2, b.value AS value2
     , c.barcode AS barcode3, c.value AS value3
FROM cte a
LEFT JOIN cte b
 ON a.email_address = b.email_address
  AND a.RN = b.RN -1
LEFT JOIN cte c
 ON a.email_address = c.email_address
  AND a.RN = c.RN -2
WHERE a.RN = 1
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5d091/2/0)

If going beyond 2 a `PIVOT` answer may be preferable.

Comment: was just writing this out; typed too slow. :)

Comment: would this work if i wanted to barcode3 and value3:
;WITH cte AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY email_address ORDER BY BURNED_BARCODE) AS RN
              FROM [gous_20140103_stylecash_store])
SELECT a.email_address, a.BURNED_BARCODE, a.BURNED_VALUE, b.BURNED_BARCODE AS barcode2, b.BURNED_VALUE AS value2, c.BURNED_BARCODE AS barcode3, c.BURNED_VALUE AS value3
FROM cte a
LEFT JOIN cte b
 ON a.email_address = b.email_address
  AND a.RN = b.RN -1
WHERE a.RN = 1
LEFT JOIN cte c
 ON a.email_address = c.email_address
  AND a.RN = c.RN -1
WHERE a.RN = 1
group by a.email_address

Comment: @johnnE Close, but you'd want to join on `c.RN-2`, and no need to `GROUP BY` since limiting to `WHERE a.RN = 1`. see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @GoatCO , this is great :) If you have the time/patience, could you explain the "ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION" part, like what exactly is it doing? Dont feel obligated to answer that. I cant google this as well :)

Comment: The `ROW_NUMBER()` function assigns a number to each row. `PARTITION BY` is optional, but used to start the numbering over for each value in that group,  ie: if you `PARTITION BY Some_Date`  then for each unique date value the numbering would start over at 1.  `ORDER BY` of course is used to define how the counting should go, and is required in the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.  Running just the inside portion of the `cte` will show you all the values being returned by the `ROW_NUMBER()`